# php form submission not working

Tags: php, forms, post, submit

I have multiple pages that I have made using this exact same method, but for some reason, no matter what I've tried, I can't get certain fields to transfer into the email fields. I get absolutely no data at all. Here is the form HTML

```
    <form action="interest.php" method="post" >                                                   <!-- BEGIN cardetail Form -->
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td width="50" class="alignRight" style="font-weight:bold;" >Year:</td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td width="112"><p name="carYear">2011</p></td>
    <td class="alignRight" style="font-weight:bold;" >Color:</td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td><p name="carColor">Red</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="alignRight" style="font-weight:bold;" >Make:</td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td ><p name="carMake">Honda</p></td>
    <td width="50" class="alignRight" style="font-weight:bold;">Trim:</td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td>Car has some sort of trim on it.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="alignRight" style="font-weight:bold;" >Model:</td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td><p name="carModel">Accord</p></td>
    <td class="alignRight" style="font-weight:bold;">Miles:</td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td><p>180,000</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="alignRight" style="font-weight:bold;">Options:</td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td colspan="4">
    <p>
        Power Windows, 
            Power Locks, 
            Keyless Entry, 
            Cruise Control, 
            Climate Control, 
            2.6L V-Tech
    </p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold;">Repairs/Maintenance:</td>
    <td width="10px"></td>
    <td colspan="4">Fuel line flush, Transmission flush, Coolant flush, Oil Change, New Oil Filter, New Fuel Filter, New Air Filter, New Radiator, Painted Driverside Door, New Tires, Brand New Wax Job, and Fully Detailed.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td class="alignRight"></td>
        <td></td>
<td><a href="#top">Back to Top</a></td>
        <td class="alignRight" style="font-weight:bold;">Price:</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="price"><p><span class="price"><?php echo $carPrice; ?>$6,000</span><input class="showInterest" type="submit" name="showInterest" id="showInterest" value="Show Interest" /></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </form>                     <!-- END cardetail Form -->
```

Here is the php code that I'm trying to get the information transferred to.

```
    <?php echo $_POST['carYear'] . " / " . $_POST['carMake'] . " / " . $_POST['carModel'] . " / " . $_POST['carColor']; ?>
```

Now when I run the code from my server, all I get is 3 "/". For some reason the $_POST isn't grabbing any data. I've tried passing it into a variable, AND just inserting the data as it is in the example. What am I doing wrong? Is there a minor typo that I'm missing?

Comment: Wait. You only have one `<input>` and it is the submit button?

Comment: Well. eventually, all the information about the cars will be pulled from SQL database, basically I just wanted to set it up so a customer could click on the interested button and automatically fill out part of the emailer form with the car info, then input their own name, phone, email. I didn't copy the entire page, just the parts that I'm trying to use right now. the rest of the page loads fine. You can checkout the page itself [link](culturalvomit.com/ericsonauto/viewcar.html) Click the button to view the final page, the only php code is what I posted above.

Comment: @JeffWalters trust me, that is not how it is done. check some tutorials on how to submit a form first

Comment: how can I get it to post then? I had the name="" in the <td> tags before, so I moved them into <p> hoping that would work. It's not really anything that I want a user to ever input into, I just want to pull the information into an emailer form that I already have setup.

Comment: Let me understand this, when a person clicks on "Show interest" what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are not getting anything is because, you are not posting anything!!

You only have one `<input>` and it is this one:

```
  <input class="showInterest" type="submit" name="showInterest"
               id="showInterest"  value="Show Interest" />
```

And, that is just a `submit` button only, It does nothing by itself. It can only submit what is inside another `<input type=''>` tag. 
ex: if you have

`<input type='text' name='carYear' />` 
You would be able to retrieve the value by saying 
`echo $_POST['carYear'];` in your PHP page.

I don't see anything there. You can't post a plain text, no matter if it is inside your `<form></form>` tags. You have to create inputs.

**edited**

Ok, put this values scripts your HTML file,

```
  <input type='text' name='carYear' value='' />
  <input type='text' name='carMake' value='' />
  <input type='text' name='carModel' value='' />
  <input type='text' name='carColor' value='' />
```

and **fill** all the `value=''` with the car details, and submit the form

Comment: So could I just make type="text" and disable? I would hate the way that looks, but I need this to work

Comment: NO. Just tell me what you want, when a person cliks on show interest

Comment: year, make, model, color. The rest, they fill out.

Comment: First `viewcar.html` should be `viewcar.php` and every car should have a unique number unless you are selling only one car

Comment: it will be once I get the database setup. My customer won't settle on a domain name, so that part is on hold unfortunately.

Comment: @JeffWalters Ok, check my edited answer, try it and tell me what you get

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any input in your form except for the submit button, this is the reason why you don't get any data in

```
    <?php echo $_POST['carYear'] . " / " . $_POST['carMake'] . " / " . $_POST['carModel'] . " / " . $_POST['carColor']; ?>
```

To have a value let's say in `$_POST['carYear']` you should add somewhere in your form

```
<input type="text" name="carYear">
```

Learn more about php forms [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Comment: Already read that. That's how most of my forms are filled out. No one ever told me that it had to be an input field before. Glad I know that now.

Comment: @JeffWalters that's how form works, i'm glad i helped you out. If you need to put a value from database just echo it after input tag and your input will be filled with your db data, and so you will be able to have in $_POST array in next page

Answer (score 0):

You are not posting anything. But, If you want to maintain your structure and actually post something. Add some hidden inputs with the values you want to post.

Your inputs would go like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="carYear" value="2011"/>
<input type="hidden" name="carMake" value="Honda"/>
<input type="hidden" name="carModel" value="Accord"/>
<input type="hidden" name="carColor" value="Red"/>
```

Comment: Ok. Just making sure I get this right. Should I have one field displaying the data for the user to read, then the hidden field so I can pull the data into the emailer form?

Comment: This is just if you want to maintain your current structure. But, if you want the same field to do both things, replace your <p>'s with inputs (type='text'). And style them with CSS

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. This saved me a lot of frustration. I guess my teacher left out some vital information when we got to form handling in PHP class. You guys helped me solve my problem quickly and with great explanations.